# $A_5$ as finite subgroup of $SO(5)$, trigonometric formulas for rotation matrix, and being a simple group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

Over the reals, $SO(2)$ and $SO(3)$ have well known trigonometric expressions as "physical" rotation matrices. I think also $SO(n)$ can be described by trigonometric functions by introducing additional angles. The alternating group $A_n$ is a finite subgroup of $SO(n)$. When going from $A_4$ to $A_5$, the alternating group becomes simple (actually simple for $n \neq 4$). Is this somehow reflected in some kind of structural change in the corresponding trigonometric representation of $SO(n)$ for $n \geqslant5$?

Comment: It should be pointed out that $A_n$ is not simple just for $n\ge 5$, but rather for $n\ne 4$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The natural permutation representation of $A_n$ as $n\times n$ matrices is not irreducible but rather it has a faithful $(n-1)$-dimensional submodule. Geometrically that can also be seen as follows. $A_{n+1}$ acts naturally as orientation preserving symmetries of a regular $(n+1)$-simplex that can be embedded symmetrically into $\Bbb{R}^n$. For example, $A_3$ can be seen as the group of rotations of an equilateral triangle, $A_4$ as rotations of a regular tetrahedron (in 3D) etc.

Comment: Don't know if that is at all what you are aiming at, but this suggests that any change you are looking for would already appear in $SO(4)$. Anyway, it is unclear to me how simplicity of a Lie group is related to simplicity of, say, irreducibly acting subgroups.

Comment: Thanks. It seems in this context perhaps $A_4$ is more special than $A_5$.